# Resolving Stacks with Return Statements

Tags: java, recursion, return

Although I think I have a solid understanding of resolving stacks in void methods, return methods really mess up my understanding of stacks. The following method particularly confuses me as I would have thought that it would return 0, but returns 12 instead.

```
public static int mystery(int n) { // where the method call is mystery(7)
    n--; // since n is decremented before the first 
         // recursive method, the first stack is method(6)

    if(n > 0)  // base case
       mystery(n);

    return n * 2; // 0 * 2 = 0?
}
```

My question is why does the method output 12 when mystery(7), if 0 is the last value to go into the stack. Wouldn't this method still follow LIFO?

Comment: Look carefully.  The recursive calls do not affect the result!   `(7 - 1) * 2` is `12`

Comment: Since your method never `return`s the result of the recursive call, what is actually returned to the main is the first call where `n==2`

Comment: @GBlodgett More precisely, the method does return value in the recursive calls, but the value is never used. First call is `7` too.

Comment: @Jai but there's never a return statement with the recursive call so how does it return a value?

Comment: @Letta You are recursively calling `mystery()`, and this method returns an `int`, so it definitely returns an `int` there. And the value of `n` in each stack belongs to the particular stack, there is no "universal" `n` that is shared by all stacks.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be like this:

```
public static int mystery(int n) { // where the method call is mystery(7)

n--; // since n is decremented before the first 
     // recursive method, the first stack is method(6)

if(n > 0)  // base case
   n = mystery(n);

return n * 2; // 0 * 2 = 0?
}
```

Now it will return 0 always.

Answer (score 0):

From the inside out:

The innermost call to `mystery` (n is 1 on entry) returns 0 to its caller. The return value is not used.

The next level of `mystery` (n is 2 on entry) returns 2 to its caller.  The return value is not used.

*...and so on...*

The next-to-outermost level of `mystery` (n is 6 on entry) returns 10 to its caller.  The return value is not used.

The outermost level of `mystery` (n is 7 on entry) returns 12 to its caller, which is the final return value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's not consider 7. Let's say your value is 3. `mystery(3)`. In this case, the function will run 3 times.

First run:

```
n = 3;
n--; // n = 2
(n > 0) so mystery(2)
```

Second run:

```
n = 2;
n--; // n = 1
(n > 0) so mystery(1)
```

Third run:

```
n = 1;
n--; // n = 0
(n = 0) so return the n*2 . And the return will be 4
```

Why? Cause the recursive function does not change the value of `n`